# Ruby switch statement always evaluates to default

Tags: ruby

If I simulate the rolling of a six-sided die as follows, it always evaluates to 6. How do I fix this?

```
def rolldice()
  roll = rand()
  case roll
    when 0..(1/6) then return 1
    when (1/6)..(2/6) then return 2
    when (2/6)..(3/6) then return 3
    when (3/6)..(4/6) then return 4
    when (4/6)..(5/6) then return 5
    else return 6
  end
end

die1 = rolldice()
puts die1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is because `1/6` is `0`. You can simply pass a range to [`rand`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.2/Kernel.html#method-i-rand):

```
def rolldice
  rand(1..6)
end
```

Comment: `(1..6).to_a.sample` also works, but is less desirable because it creates a temporary array.

Answer (score 1):

When you divide two integers then the result will be an integer so your code is actually doing this:

```
when 0..0 then return 1
when 0..0 then return 2
when 0..0 then return 3
when 0..0 then return 4
when 0..0 then return 5
else return 6
```

Try this simple example in IRB:

```
1 / 6
=> 0
```

Comment: Nobody shows IRB output demonstrating integer vs. float division and the results. Add that and you'll have the most succinct answer.

Answer (score 1):

Stefan is right but the answer doesn't clearly explain your problem.

The problem is that `rand()` gives you a Float (which can have numbers after the decimal point).

But in the `case` statement you are using ranges such as  `0..(1/6)`.

The problem there is that the numbers in `(1/6)` are both integers, so the answer is an integer.  That's why `(1/6)` is `0`, it's rounded.

You could also solve the problem by using `when` ranges such as:

```
when (3.0/6)..(4.0/6) then return 4
```

Looking at `(3.0/6)` we have a Float divided by an Integer, the result is a Float, in this case `0.5`.

But in the end it's probably best to follow Stefan's suggestion.  Instead of using `rand` for a Float from `0` to `1`, we can use a range.  Some options:

```
rand(1..6)    # Returns an Integer from 1 to 6
rand(6)   # Returns an Integer from 0 to 5
```

If you use the first case, then you can rewrite the when as just `when 5`...  or so on.  In this case, because all you want is to return the number, you don't even need the `case` statement, hence Stefan's shorter answer of just calling `rand` directly and using that value.

Answer (score 0):

*Case* statement is not the best option to you.  It may fit best for texts or fix values.  Assuming that you're doing an RPG application, the *Switch* may be more useful to choose what to do with weapons/armors.

*Case* is a more elegant way to write a lot of if elses, but behave almost the same way.  Before writing the *Case* you should test the conditions using irb (or rails console if you prefer).  This make things easier.

Case also do a lot of comparisons, in this particular case they are not necessary, using the rand() directly will perform better and the code will be simpler.  Note that rand(6) will return from 0 to 5, just sum 1 to get the d6.

```
def rolldice
   return rand(6)+1
end
```

Comment: To clarify, Ruby doesn't have a "switch" statement. It has `case`, which we use to implement switch logic.

Comment: Thank you!  I will modify.  Programming in multiple languages cause my brain to bug sometimes.